# Why container created by docker stack has 3 ip address, and they are different from what's inside service inspect

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I created 3 services across 2 nodes using docker stack deploy

i looked into one service, first inside container

it has 3 ip addresses of different subnets

```
      ifconfig
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:00:02:05
                inet addr:10.0.2.5  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
                RX packets:141427 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:90456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:16495496 (15.7 MiB)  TX bytes:62287111 (59.4 MiB)

      eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:13:00:03
                inet addr:172.19.0.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:355 (355.0 B)  TX bytes:230 (230.0 B)

      eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:ff:00:07
                inet addr:10.255.0.7  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
                RX packets:253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:233 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:16484 (16.0 KiB)  TX bytes:17135 (16.7 KiB)

      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
                UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
                RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
                RX bytes:1050 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1050 (1.0 KiB)
```

but they are all different from what i got from docker service inspect

```
        "VirtualIPs": [
            {
                "NetworkID": "u0n4343zozic7awn0985441pd",
                "Addr": "10.255.0.6/16"
            },
            {
                "NetworkID": "mi1l10o7ysnv5jipp8c9wyrvr",
                "Addr": "10.0.2.4/24"
            }
        ]
```

so my question is why the containers has 3 ip, and what they do?
also what do the VirtualIPs stand for? what are they used for?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you have also configured an overlay network inside your stack? Then it would be the following:

eth0: is the container ip adress on the overlay network - this is because the docker network created for your service will also have a CIDR mask. You can just resolve your containers via a nslookup against the service task: `nslookup tasks.'

eth1: is the iptables linked ip adress from your docker host from the docker engine.

eth2: my guess is, that this one is coming from Weave networks for example - did you have ever installed another third party overlay network like weave? If yes, delete it and for example run  `weave reset`.

For the virtual ips: If you start a stack service including an overlay network, your service will receive a virtual ip address - I guess for weave too. Read more at https://success.docker.com/Architecture/Docker_Reference_Architecture%3A_Designing_Scalable%2C_Portable_Docker_Container_Networks

From the linked Docker page:

> myservice resolves to the Virtual IP (VIP) of that service which is
>   internally load balanced to the individual task IP addresses.
>   Container names resolve as well, albeit directly to their IP
>   addresses.

Therefore you can nslookup  and will get the virtual ip. General, this is an advanced topic, where you will have to read a lot about it.